# How to limit the number of rows in dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, sqldataadapter

Code to refer

```
 [WebMethod]

 public static string GetData()
 {
      string query = "SELECT * FROM tblCountry";
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
      return GetData(cmd).GetXml();
 }
 private static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
 {
      string strConnString = @"Data Source=.\sqlExpress;Initial Catalog=dbTest;Integrated  Security=SSPI; pooling=false";
      using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
      {
          using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
          {
             cmd.Connection = con;
             sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
             using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
             {
                sda.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
             }
          }
      }
 }
```

See more at: [Link](http://codingresolved.com/discussion/306/how-to-fill-gridview-in-asp-net-using-jquery/p1#sthash.6MIUlhYS.dpuf)

> The query returns 20 rows and i need to show ten rows alone. Without any alteration in query is there any possibility to limit the data in dataset.Suggest some ideas

Comment: Rather than using `sda.Fill...`, maybe use a DataReader in a (limited) loop

Comment: Or SELECT TOP(10) * FROM tblCountry ORDER BY ... Something

Comment: @ Devcon2 He is asking without alteration in query..

Comment: Why don't you want to alter the query ??

Comment: Sometimes you may want to limit records returned without altering the query because you are not in control of the query. You may want to let your users run a query but you dont want to bring back gigs of data. This is the exact reason I want to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an overload of `Fill` that takes the start and end record index.

```
var ds = new DataSet; //using means the DataSet will go out of scope so you can't return it!
sda.Fill(1, 10, ds.Tables.Add("MyTable"));
return ds; //it now contains a table called "MyTable".
```

You can find more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59wzthcw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

But like most commenters here, I'd be much more in favour of modifying the query *if at all possible*

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

```
var rows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Take(10);
```

Now you can also convert these rows into a datatable like this

```
DataTable limitedTable = rows.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Comment: Was about to post this answer. Remember to add reference to your project for System.Data.DataSetExtensions or this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

How strict is your requirement to not alter the query?  Can you prepend some text to the query?

If so, you can use [SET ROWCOUNT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx).

Example:

```
string query = "SET ROWCOUNT 10;"
query += "SELECT * FROM tblCountry";
```

Answer (score -2):

```
string query = "SELECT TOP 10 FROM tblCountry";
```

You can make a query like this, to return only 10 rows.